# why dropzonejs programatically does not work fine?

Tags: javascript, image-uploading, dropzone.js

I'm developing an web application. For file upload, I want to use [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com)
 programatically, But it does not work well. You can see the sample on `jsfiddle.net` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q55pym8x/).

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDropZone", { url: "upload.php"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `autoDiscover` feature to false, otherwise dropzone will load with default options and throw an error `dropzone already attached`, and since you are using a div the default initialization is not going to work either because a url is needed.

html:

```
<body onload="me()">
   <h1>Drag&amp;Drop Multiple Files Upload using DropzoneJS</h1>
   <div class="image_upload_div">
      <div id="myDropZone" class="dropzone" ></div>     
   </div>
</body>
```

js:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var me = function () {
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDropZone", {
        url: "upload.php"
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wallek876/q55pym8x/2/)

Comment: Thanks very very much.

Comment: The trick which did it for me, and is not clear from the documentation, is that you still need to keep the dropzone class in your element, otherwise it does not work. Not sure why this is needed: if I call a Dropzone in an element, it should be a dropzone, period, no matter if that is of class dropzone or not. I was doing this to avoid having to do Dropzone.autodiscover = false;, but clearly my workaround does not work.

Comment: And I have just discovered: your fiddle is just working because of a side-effect of loading the scripts in head (what fiddle does): since when dropzone.js is loaded and exectued, the body is not yet present, there are no dropzone elements to attach to, and then you can manually create your dropzone. The right way would be to tell Dropzone not to attach at all after loading, but you can not do this since either Dropzone is not loaded and you can not set `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;`, or Dropzone is loaded and it is already too late: it has attached. The head solution is a hack.

Comment: @gonvaled I am not an expert on how the pages are loaded, but i am going to try to explain the process, or at least how I think the process works. Even if dropzone library is included in the head and loaded before the DOM is ready, what btw I think is a common thing, it waits to try to attach to the elements until the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired, And this is personal, but I tend to include my scripts inside the body at the end, So the script is loaded before the `DOMContentLoaded` is fired, and thus the `Dropzone.atuoDiscover` is set to `false` when the dropzone library checks for it.